# QFT in A Nutshell Zee I.3.1

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, causality, propagator, textbook-erratum

In Zee's solution for (I.3.1) on p. 483 at the back of the book (2003 edition) he writes:

$$D(x)=-\frac{1}{2(2\pi)^2 r}\int_0^\infty \frac{dk~k}{\sqrt{k^2 +m^2}}(e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr})=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2 r}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{dk~k}{\sqrt{k^2 +m^2}}e^{ikr}.$$

I have seen from someone else's question on SE ["QFT Propagator across spacelike separation"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409906/) that the sign of $k$ can be switched. But that does not explain it. By switching the sign of one of the $k$'s how would this not just equal zero?

I looked at another posting on SE about this same problem ["Exponential decay of Feynman propagator outside the lightcone"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314821/exponential-decay-of-feynman-propagator-outside-the-lightcone), but it did not answer my question.

Reference: Quantum field theory in a nutshell, Anthony Zee, 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2003 edition of the book has a typo. In rightmost expression, the correct limits are $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, not $\int_{0}^{\infty}$.

The second part of
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{dk \ k}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} (e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr}) \quad\quad -(1)
\end{equation}

is

\begin{equation}
-\int_0^\infty \frac{dk \ k}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} e^{-ikr}
\end{equation}

which after a change of variables $k \rightarrow -k$ becomes:

\begin{equation}
-\int_0^{-\infty} \frac{dk \ k}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} e^{ikr} = \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{dk \ k}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} e^{ikr}
\end{equation}

Putting this back in (1), you get:

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dk \ k}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} e^{ikr}
\end{equation}

This is the correct expression, which is in the second edition of the book on page 545.

Errata for Zee's book can be verified here: https://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/zee/books/quantum-field-theory-nutshell/errata-and-addenda